# Swift: 'Tap to Begin' button - delete itself

Tags: ios, xcode, button, swift, ibaction

I have a tap to begin button in my main view controller. It is linked to an IBAction that will detect when it is touched. However, I am wondering what would be the best way of hiding the button: deleted, moved off screen, or hidden completely - and what code should I put in my IBAction to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just hide it. Create an outlet connection so you can reference the button as an class instance property, then set its `hidden` property to `true` from the tap handler:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var btnBegin: UIButton!

@IBAction func didTapBegin() {
    ...
    btnBegin.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Have you created the outlet connection from interface builder to the `btnBegin` property?

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't connected!